# jQuery Click and following function is not called

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

The below code works in Chrome and Firefox but not in Edge.

On click a button, it should create a programmatic click on input file so the user can upload the attachment.

Once the user selects the attachment, the file change is detected and uploaded using Ajax call.

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(document).on("click",".upload-btn",function(){
            jQuery(document).find(".upload").click();
            watchCoveringLetterUpload();
        });
    });

    function watchCoveringLetterUpload() {
    var target = jQuery(document).find(".upload");
    var textType = /text.*/;
    target.change(function(e) {
        console.log(e)

})
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sv3oougf/   ---- original code

https://jsfiddle.net/sv3oougf/1/ ---- tested with self invoking function

Please check the console.log, the function called is not executed in IE but executed in Chrome.

Comment: There's no such thing as IE Edge. IE is a separate browser from Edge.

Answer (score 0):

use id's instead of using classes for referencing input types and it will work.

check this code tested on edge

```js
  (function() {


      function watchCoveringLetterUpload() {
          console.log("function is called");
          var target = jQuery(document).find("#upload");
          var textType = /text.*/;
          target.change(function(e) {
              console.log(e)
              file = target[0].files[0];
              console.log("file", file);
          });
      }

      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          jQuery(document).on("click", ".upload-btn", function() {
              jQuery(document).find("#upload").click();
              watchCoveringLetterUpload();
          });
      });

  })(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" style="display:none" id="upload">
<button class="upload-btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: Still the other testing is going on and couldnt confirm the output. Will update once its done.